# How does "keepalive" functionality work with sockets?

Tags: sockets

In sockets, keepalive will not close the socket. The client sends a keepalive flag to the server and if the server agrees the connection will not be closed. If I understand the concept well, the client will send a keepalive packet (which contains null data) to the server whenever the client has no data to send.

However, when can a socket be closed?

The following are the scenarios I can think of

1. the server/client specifically close the connection
2. timeout exceptions

Can the router close a connection?

Comment: What application layer protocol are we talking about here? A router typically won't close a connection. A firewall or IDS might determine it as in violation of some rule and sent RST (on TCP connections) or start bidirectionally dropping packets for the endpoint combination.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: a router CAN close idle connections after awhile.  FTP is a notorious example of that. During a long file transfer, a router may close the idle command connection unless the client employs TCP keep-alives on the command connection so the router does not close it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I never said that they don't. I wrote that they typically will not. Additionally, the FTP server software is often the cause of idle connections being terminated. It's also widely recognized as a misconfiguration if a router is terminating idle connections for a connection it is not acting as the immediate upstream provider for. ISPs usually have idle limits of 1-2 hours for certain types of connections, but only usually for those that are metered or dial on demand. But as always, configurations vary by  locality, because of the different types of infrastructures.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray: think of an FTP client that is sitting behind a non-FTP-aware router/firewall (and there are plenty of them in existence) connecting to an FTP server on the outside. An FTP-aware router/firewall analyzes the FTP command traffic and knows when a file transfer is in progress, so it knows when not to close an idle command connection during a long transfer. A non-FTP-aware router/firewall does not do that analysis, so it can (and usually does) close an idle command connection. That has nothing to do with the FTP server itself.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing two different things called keepalive.

1. In HTTP keepalive, it is on by default from HTTP 1.1, and the client has to specifically request it to be turned off. In HTTP 1.0 there was no such thing but there was an informal conventions to request it: a `Connection: keep-alive` header.  When a keep-alive is used, neither party closes the connection after the HTTP response has been sent/received.  When a keep-alive is not used, both parties close the connection.
2. In TCP keepalive, the TCP stack sends a byte with a sequence number lower than what has already been ACKed, which should provoke the receiver into sending an ACK with the current sequence number.

In HTTP or TCP the connection can really be closed any time, and the peer just has to detect and cope with that.